# How to Pass the innerHTML of a <td> to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I  have the following HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td>value 1</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>value 3</td>
  <td>value 3</td>
  <td onlick="somefunction(The random number)"></td>
<tr>
```

Problems:

- the table is generated and I cannot pass a ID or class.
- the number is random and I do not know it until the table is generated.

**How can I pass the value of the random number (12 in this case ) to the function?**

Comment: I have no idea what you mean as, given your code structure, the random number ***is*** being passed to the function. Also, the question itself appears to have nothing to do with passing the `innerHTML` of the `td` cell?

Comment: if the values are dynamic then why don't you put the var which outputs the `12` in the `td`?

Comment: @Teemu 4th one seems to be accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your constraints right, then following may help you

```
<script> console.cog($("td:nth-child(2)").html()) </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this . the math.random() function generates the random no 0.0 - 99.99 and Math.floor() function is used get round figure 
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>value 1</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>value 3</td>
        <td>value 3</td>
        <td class="random" onclick="someFunction(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))"></td>
    <tr>
</table>
```